# Accessing NREL data for specific wind turbines?

Tags: data-request, usa, machine-learning, weather, energy

I am looking for a specific data set from NREL ([US National Renewable Energy Laboratory](http://www.nrel.gov/)) western wind resources dataset, but I am not sure how to navigate the site to access and download the file.

The data I am looking for is the 10-minute data for years 01/2004 to 06/2005 for machine learning training data, and the 10-minute data for years 7/2005 to 12/2006 as test data.

The turbines I would like to obtain this data from are Casper (ID = 23167), Hesperia (ID = 2028), Las Vegas (ID = 6272), Reno (ID = 11637), and Vantage (ID = 28981).

These are all values given in a paper on machine learning, and I would like to use the same data these researchers used but conduct different experiments on them with different algorithms.

Do you know how to access this data on the NREL site so I can download it as a file? If possible, please post either the instructions or the link to the source.

Comment: what site? (it seems like this is a question for NREL)